# Changing Home Background

Tags: java, android, xml

Is it possible to change the background image of the home screen from an app?

If so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since API Level 5 (I believe that's Android 1.6? I may be mistaken) there is the [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) class that you can use to do this.

Simply create an instance using `getInstance()`, then use one of the `set` methods (`setBitmap()`, `setResource()`, or `setStream()`) to apply the wallpaper.

For instance:

```
WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
wm.setBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: So if I wanted to set the background to a drawable, what would the code be?

Comment: You'd actually first have to convert the Drawable to a Bitmap, since there's no setDrawable method.